# Error import module Facebook 4.2.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have error when I import facebook-sdk-4.2.0

> D:\Document\android\FunnyPhoto\facebook\build.gradle
>
> (16, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project '-facebook'-

And i have code in here

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            project.version = matcher[0][1]
            return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
        throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'Facebook Platform License'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    // JDK 1.8 is more strict then 1.7. Have JDK 1.8 behave like 1.7 for javadoc generation
    if (org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaVersion() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    }
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

Comment: in addition to whats in "build.gradle" , dont u have to download the 4.2 FB sdk?

Comment: i download 4.2 FB SDK and i import that but I cant see module fb in Project Structure

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started  double check  the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those constants are defined at the top level gradle.properties file. If you imported the facebook sdk to a module in your project, you should merge the contents of that file into your top level gradle.properties file, alternatively you can add them to the build.gradle file in Facebook.

All of this is unnecessary though, there is a very easy way to integrate your project with the Facebook Android SDK via maven. All you need is steps 4-5 in this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio